# vuetify динамическая шапка таблицы / динамические слоты

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Как сделать так, чтобы динамически можно было добавлять слот вместе с чекбоксом
в таблицу vuetify, например headers1 / headers2 и тд поместить в цикл

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  class="elevation-1"
>

  <template v-slot:item.header1="{ item }">
    <v-simple-checkbox
      v-model="item.header1"
    ></v-simple-checkbox>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:item.header2="{ item }">
    <v-simple-checkbox
      v-model="item.header2"
    ></v-simple-checkbox>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:item.header3="{ item }">
    <v-simple-checkbox
      v-model="item.header3"
    ></v-simple-checkbox>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:item.header4="{ item }">
    <v-simple-checkbox
      v-model="item.header4"
    ></v-simple-checkbox>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <template
    v-for="boolHeader in boolHeaders"
    v-slot:[`item.${boolHeader.value}`]="{ item }"
  >
    <v-simple-checkbox
      v-model="item[boolHeader.value]"
      :key="boolHeader.value"
    ></v-simple-checkbox>
  </template>
```